# PyQGIS | Write in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I wrote simple code to check the xlwt module in Qgis. But I receive an error.

```
from xlwt import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

sheet1.write(0,0,'Hello!')

wb.save("test12.xls")
```

---

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlwt\CompoundDoc.py", line 262, in save
    f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test12.xls'
```

I need to solve this problem so that I can then take specific data from different attribute tables and write them to an Excel file.

Comment: The code presented here is pure Python rather PyQGIS, and so should be researched at [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify a path, the file is created in the `os.getcwd()` directory. Do you have no writing rights there is a mistake.

Test with a full pathname `wb.save("c:/tar/test12.xls")` in a writable directory